# Создание плеера в Android

Tags: mediaplayer, android

Решил создать многофункциональный плеер. Хочется узнать, что мне нужно будет для создание полноценного плеера (дополнительные библиотеки, движки...), и какие библиотеки посоветуете для создание красивого интерфейса. Заранее спасибо.

Comment: смотря какого плеера для начала. Аудио или видео. Хм. Какие форматы он будет поддерживать. На баловство похоже...

Comment: > что мне нужно будет ........ и какие библиотеки посоветуете

Движок RTFM и прямые_руки.dll

Comment: @Nofate, я гуглю, не как не могу найти этот двиг =(

Comment: @Gorets, я по этой странице 3 раза гонял поиск через Ctrl+F, но тоже не нашел ТЗ на многофункциональный плеер. Видимо оно вместе с движком RTFM в одном месте лежит. Будет одно - отыщется и другое.

Comment: для Аудио,и не баловство это,а серьезно)

Comment: @ramin, твой вопрос звучит как то так, "я решил стать директором газпрома, покажите где расписатся и мой кабинет.". Не  задавай вопросы о вещах о которых у тебя нету понятия, попробуй для начала провести свое иследование вопроса, сделать выводы, расчитать силы.

Comment: я про то что у тебя вопрос не формы "посмотрите я чтото делал и у меня не получилось", а формы "у меня есть задание - погуглите за меня". В ответе масимум на этот вопрос можт быть пару первых ссылок из гугла по запросу android audio player example.

Comment: Я же не сказал сделайте за меня,я просто спросил какой функционал,какой движок,и может какие та доп библиотеки нужны.

Comment: я уже использовал MediaPlayer,MediaController,понятия та есть,просто нужен был совет ,что может лучше подойти для этого.

Comment: Нужно сформулировать, что именно тебя в медиаплеере не устраивает. Типа, "мне нужно сделать вот так вот, а с медиаплеером так не получается". Сейчас вопрос слишком уж абстрактен.